# Rally App SDK 2.0: Ext.Element method "unselectable" isn't so normalized

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

Even though the "unselectable" method is supposed to disable text selection, it does not function properly in IE, at least IE8. The text cursor is still present, and allows for input.

I should assume that it also does not work in IE9, as the Microsoft equivalent CSS attribute "-ms-user-select" has only recently been introduced in IE10, which has not been "officially" released, and is also not currently supported by Windows 7.

I should also question why the webkit version ("-webkit-user-select") is not included, either. I understand that webkit is a fork of khtml, and it seems to work as intended in Chrome, but I still question the omission.

```
/**
* Disables text selection for this element (normalized across browsers)
* @return {Ext.Element} this
*/
unselectable : function(){
    var me = this;
    me.dom.unselectable = "on";

    me.swallowEvent("selectstart", true);
    me.applyStyles("-moz-user-select:-moz-none;-khtml-user-select:none;");
    me.addCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'unselectable');

    return me;
}
```

Is there a simple way to modify this code in order to provide proper functionality in versions of IE older than IE10?

**EDIT**: I am having a bit of trouble getting this to work. I have inserted the following in the onReady call, but before the app.

```
(function() {
    var Ext = window.Ext4 || window.Ext;

    Ext.override(Ext.dom.Element, {
        unselectable: function() {
            var me = this;
            me.dom.unselectable = "on";

            me.swallowEvent("selectstart", true);

            me.applyStyles([
                '-moz-user-select: none;', 
                '-khtml-user-select: none;', 
                '-webkit-touch-callout: none;', 
                '-webkit-user-select: none;', 
                '-ms-user-select: none;', 
                'user-select: none'
            ].join());

            me.addCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'unselectable');

            return me;
        },

        selectable: function() {
            var me = this;
            me.dom.unselectable = "off";
            // Prevent it from bubles up and enables it to be selectable
            me.on('selectstart', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                return true;
            });

            me.applyStyles([
                '-moz-user-select: text;', 
                '-khtml-user-select: text;', 
                '-webkit-touch-callout: text;', 
                '-webkit-user-select: text;', 
                '-ms-user-select: text;', 
                'user-select: text'
            ].join());

            me.removeCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'unselectable');
            return me;
        },
    });
})();
```

However, I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Element' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `me.dom.unselectable = "on";` is there to handle `unselectable` for IE9 and lower. This will add an attribute to the element like `<div unselectable="on">blah</div>`, and that should cause the div's text to no longer be editable. Is that not working for you?

Unfortunately Ext's `unselectable` and `selectable` appear to not quite handle webkit, you can fix that by overriding the methods. How to override the method depends on which version of the SDK you are using.

## For App SDK 2.0p and 2.0p2

These versions of the SDK are built against ExtJS 4.0.7. In Ext 4.0, you can't use `Ext.override` to patch up `Ext.Element`. So you need to be a bit more manual and alter the prototype:

```
Ext.core.Element.prototype.unselectable = function() {
   var me = this;
   me.dom.unselectable = "on";

   me.swallowEvent("selectstart", true);

   me.applyStyles([
    '-moz-user-select: none;', 
    '-khtml-user-select: none;', 
    '-webkit-touch-callout: none;', 
    '-webkit-user-select: none;', 
    '-ms-user-select: none;', 
    'user-select: none'
    ].join());

   me.addCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'unselectable');

   return me;
};

Ext.core.Element.prototype.selectable = function() {
   var me = this;
   me.dom.unselectable = "off";
   // Prevent it from bubles up and enables it to be selectable
   me.on('selectstart', function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       return true;
   });

   me.applyStyles([
    '-moz-user-select: text;', 
    '-khtml-user-select: text;', 
    '-webkit-touch-callout: text;', 
    '-webkit-user-select: text;', 
    '-ms-user-select: text;', 
    'user-select: text'
    ].join());

   me.removeCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'unselectable');
   return me;
};
```

You should do this as the very first thing inside `Rally.onReady()`

## For App SDK 2.0p3 and on

The App SDK for 2.0p3 and forward is built against ExtJS 4.1. They changed Ext.Element to support `Ext.override`, so here we can do a slightly cleaner solution (this is basically what I originally posted):

```
Ext.override(Ext.dom.Element, {
    unselectable: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.dom.unselectable = "on";

        me.swallowEvent("selectstart", true);

        me.applyStyles([
            '-moz-user-select: none;', 
            '-khtml-user-select: none;', 
            '-webkit-touch-callout: none;', 
            '-webkit-user-select: none;', 
            '-ms-user-select: none;', 
            'user-select: none'
        ].join());

        me.addCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'unselectable');

        return me;
    },

    selectable: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.dom.unselectable = "off";
        // Prevent it from bubles up and enables it to be selectable
        me.on('selectstart', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            return true;
        });

        me.applyStyles([
            '-moz-user-select: text;', 
            '-khtml-user-select: text;', 
            '-webkit-touch-callout: text;', 
            '-webkit-user-select: text;', 
            '-ms-user-select: text;', 
            'user-select: text'
        ].join());

        me.removeCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'unselectable');
        return me;
    }
 });
```

In both cases, just slightly tweaking the function to also add styles for webkit, IE, etc.

Comment: Can you take a look at the edited original post, and possibly give me an understanding of what I am doing wrong in terms of code definition/placement?

Comment: Gah! I gave you really bad advice :-/ Part of the problem is this has changed a good deal in Ext 4.1. Give me a bit I am going to totally redo my answer.

Comment: ok, redid my answer to handle both versions of the App SDK, you should find the `2.0p2` section of my answer works for you. Let me know if not.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't quite seem to work as it should, unless I am misunderstanding the functionality. The text cursor still appears in the textbox in IE, and input is still allowed. It is just not selectable. I am not sure if it should be handling both these cases, which it seems to do in Chrome, and likely Firefox, but my workaround involved manipulating the onselect attribute of the multiobjectpicker I'm working with: document.getElementById(this.inputEl.id).setAttribute('onkeydown', 'return false;');

Comment: That's one way to do it. I think `unselectable` in IE is meant more for divs and the like. What about using `readonly` on the inputEl?

Comment: That is not quite as satisfactory, as the tab/window is still given the focus of backspace, so if a user decides they want to press that key, it will affect the page, rather than just that input field. I think setting the onkeydown attribute is preferable, as it firstly does not allow the user to navigate in the text box with the arrow keys, which is allowed with readonly, and it also does not produce the result described above, if backspace is pressed.